# Change url in backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am new to backbone. I want to change the url in browser using backbone. Issue is backbone is only replacing last paramter after `#`.

**Example**

```
http://localhost:3000/home#projects
```

**After running following line**

```
Backbone.history.navigate( "welcome-user", { trigger: true, replace: true } )
```

**Output is**

```
http://localhost:3000/home#welcome-user
```

**I want**

```
http://localhost:3000/#welcome-user
```

I know there is something very simple what i am missing...

Answer (score 1):

Backbone only manages the URL fragments after the location it's run from. In other words, if you want to have a URL of `http://localhost:3000/#welcome-user`, your Backbone app has to be run from `index.html`, not from `home.html`

Answer (score 1):

You can get (almost) this if you enable pushState when you start Backbone.history

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`

Basically, rather than replace the hash, it replaces the entire url. So if you were on

`http://localhost:3000/home`

and ran

`Backbone.history.navigate( "welcome-user", { trigger: true, replace: true } )`

you would end up at

`http://localhost:3000/welcome-user`

(Technically you asked for `http://localhost:3000/#welcome-user`, with the hash - but I believe pushState in general is what you are looking for)

Keep in mind that pushState support is good, but [not universal](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions above don't meet what you want, you can always do :

```
Backbone.history.navigate( "welcome-user", { trigger: false } )
```

This will update your url without doing anything else.